# Why for of loop accepts the const keyword?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

A variable declared with the `const` keyword cannot be reinitialised. So, why the `const` keyword works for `for of` loop? For instance, if I have a loop like `for(const x of array){...code here...}`.
Why it works instead of throwing an error as in the case of `for(const x=0;x<array.length;x++){...code here...}`?
Is it due to the fact that the latter mentioned `for loop` is reinitializing the value of variable `x`  but, only declaring it once, in other words - the variable `x` is declared for the entire loop.
But, what about the `for of` loop? Is it redeclaring the value of `x` each time an iteration is done? 
 If not, then what factors make the former mentioned `for of` loop work?

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, you set const x to zero, and then attempt to alter the value with x++. As the name implies, you cannot alter the value of a constant after it's declared. If you attempted to x++ inside the for/of loop it would also throw an error. Presumably, your for/of loop only reads the value of x and does not alter it (I say presumably because you did not share the code for this portion).

Answer (score 1):

The traditional `for` loop is a staple of many languages, and often takes a form like

```
for(x=0;x<array.length;x++)
```

This construct works due to the fact that the `x` is visible not only inside the loop, but also *between iterations* - so that the `x++` works. JavaScript's `for` loops were designed to work similarly. A variable declared in the declaration of a `for` loop is visible throughout the loop body, and between iterations. (things get a bit stranger with `let`, but that's not really relevant to the issue here)

`for..of` is a different beast entirely. Despite it using the same word - `for` - as the `for(;;)` construct, it works quite differently. `for..of` invokes the iterator of the object for each iteration, and the values returned by the iterator aren't initialized before the loop - they're specific *to each iteration*, so having something like `x++` wouldn't make much sense.

`for..of`, in psuedocode:

```
iterator = getIteratorFromObject();
loop {
  if (iterator.done) break;
  nextValue = iterator();
  // execute loop body with nextValue
}
```

The value returned by the iterator, when initialized with `const` (which has block scope, not function scope), makes sense to be scoped only to the block of that particular iteration. (If you tried to reassign the `const` identifier, just like in a traditional `for` loop, you'd get an error.)

Unlike a traditional `for`, there's not really any initial value to be initialized (other than the iterator, but the consumption of the iterator is abstracted behind the JavaScript engine).